# JSrender: cannot access parent variable inside if condition

Tags: javascript, jsrender

as the title says, the problem is clear:

within the construction:

```
{{if is_completed == 1}}
 <div>
   <p>{{:#parent.parent.data.myproperty}}</p>
 </div>
{{/if}}
```

the parent properties are not visible!

I solved it by creating construction like:{{for movies ~myproperty=myproperty}} in parent loop, and ~myproperty is visible inside IF conditions, but what if I have several variables, what if I have many-level nesting data structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{{if ...}}` block adds another view, so means you need to add a .parent to step up through that view, as in: `{{:#parent.parent.parent.data.myproperty}}`

You can pass in variables as you said (`~myproperty=...`) and they will be visible to any depth of nesting.

Your variable can be an object too such as the current data object:  `~myObj=#data`:

```
{{sometag a=b ~myObj=#data}}
    ....
    {{:~myObj.myproperty}}
    ...
{{/sometag}}
```

so you don't need a separate variable for each property.

You can also access the top-level data object and drill down from there:

`{{:~root.foo...myproperty}}`.

And finally you can use `#get("item")` to step up through any number of `{{if}}` blocks and get the nearest "item" view (i.e. the item view for a repeating `{{for ...}}` block).

So you would write:

`{{:#get("item").data.myproperty}}`

Comment: Thank you, Boris, your solutions helped.